# Gradle - How to execute command line in doLast and get exit code?

Tags: gradle

```
task executeScript() {

    doFirst {
        exec {
            ignoreExitValue true
            commandLine "sh", "process.sh"
        }
    }

    doLast {
        if (execResult.exitValue == 0) {
            print "Success"
        } else {
            print "Fail"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
> Could not get unknown property 'execResult' for task ':core:executeScript' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

If I move the `commandLine` to configuration part everything works fine. But I want `commandLine` to be in action block so it wont run every time we execute some other gradle tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gradle `type` for your task

```
task executeScript(type : Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', 'process.sh'
    ignoreExitValue true

    doLast {
        if(execResult.exitValue == 0) {
            println "Success"
        } else {
            println "Fail"
        }
    }
}
```

This will work for you...

> You can read more about the `Exec task` [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

Comment: Thanks. But setting `ignoreExitValue true` still throws gradle exception for me.

Comment: Very weird, which Gradle release are you using?

Comment: Problem with command line args. Resolved it https://discuss.gradle.org/t/ignoreexitvalue-is-not-working/25593

Answer (score 0):

Alternative syntax to execute external command and get its return code:

```
doLast {
    def process = "my command line".execute()
    process.waitFor()
    println "Exit code: " + process.exitValue()
}
```