# || operator in Gradle Task commandLine

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Good day. It is necessary to make a decision to run the second command based on the results of the previous one.

I need to check if npm package is installed and if it doesn't exist start installing. `npm list -g package` (if the package does not exist, this command will return a value different from 0) and `npm install -g package` commands are used for the issue. It is easy to execute the logic in a terminal using `||` operator:

```java
npm list -g package || npm install -g package
```

Then I created `installPackage` task in *gradle.build* file:

```java
task installPackage(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'npm', 'list', '-g', 'package', '||', 'npm', 'install', '-g', 'package'
}
```

And none of the commands work. In fact, the result is displayed as if `npm list -g` command was used.

Is there a way to do this without using third-party tools or plugins? What options could be used? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a question about execute multiple commands [Gradle -- execute multiple commands from task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561014/gradle-execute-multiple-commands-from-task), but it doesn't support `&&` or `||`. Just pick from below solutions that make sense to you. Personally I prefer solution 1.

#### 1. Put your command in a script and call the script

- More flexible
- More readable (as you don't need to use ',' to separate the command)
- But need to refer to another file

```
task installPackageWithScript(type: Exec) {
    commandLine('sh', './bin/installPackage.sh')
}
```

#### 2. Refer to [Gradle - How to execute command line in doLast and get exit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443448/gradle-how-to-execute-command-line-in-dolast-and-get-exit-code), get the exit code from first command to determine whether second command is needed.

- No need to refer other file
- But less readable and maintainable

```
task installPackageInline(type: Exec) {
    commandLine('npm', 'list', '-g', 'package')
    doLast {
        if (execResult.exitValue == 0) {
            println "list Success"
        } else {
            println "list Fail, run install"
            exec { commandLine('npm', 'install', '-g', 'package') }
        }
    }
}
```